# MacBook Pro mid 2012 screen boot glitch when booting into Windows 7

Tags: windows, screen

I am attempting to use Windows 7 for overall looks. (I am aware of the risks and I don‘t care.) However, whenever I attempt to boot into the partition that I installed it on, The following occurs.

1. The screen goes black.
2. Next, the top of the screen creates this strange loading flickering effect.
3. Finally, it stops and reverts to a black screen.

I have Open Core installed and that didn't change the boot process. Even without it the same results occur. I have used Windows 7 with and without UEFI booting. I suspect something is wrong with the recovery drive. If someone can, please respond, because I haven't seen anyone else experience this. The strangest part is that Windows 7 used to work and stopped after I uninstalled it once.

Here‘s a an image for description:

[image]

Heres another image with stock bootloader[image]

Comment: How have you changed the installation procedure since *" Windows 7 used to work"*? I pretty sure the installation procedure which used to work did not involve installing Windows 7 to UEFI boot.

Comment: no i haven't, I tried without UEFI boot, but that didn't change anything, i even ensured that the iso was genuine, I even used macOS high sierra and tried bootcamp from there but nothing changed, before the boot process was successful and i was able to install bootcamp drivers, but now everytime i boot into the installation disk (with or without uefi booting capabilities) this black bar with a greenish loading effect with 4 dots pops up at the top of the screen, it sometimes flashes a red bar and reboots altogether.

Comment: You mention ISO, then later you mention disk. Did you burn the ISO to a DVD, then tried booting from the optical drive? I am not sure, because some mid 2012 MacBook Pro models have an optical drive and some do not. Also, are you trying to install 32 or 64 bit Windows 7? Does your Windows 7 include SP1?

Comment: my apologies i meant installation media not disk, i never used a DVD. Yes, mine does have an optical drive, for the most part, the ISO i used doesn't or does include SP1 and has always been x64. im aware people say you can't boot into a usb if you have an optical drive, but i don't think thats the problem because i did use a usb on this macbook and it worked.

Comment: I believe 64 bit Windows 7 should be installed to BIOS boot on your Mac. Apple explicitly states Windows 7 should have SP1. Users have posted where they have installed without SP1 on their Mac, but I don't know or remember if any of these Macs were the same as yours. I can suggest two methods of installation. The first involves EFI booting a Windows 10 installer, then using the Windows 10 installer to install Windows 7. The other is to use a virtual machine to install Windows 7. After you finish installing Windows 7, the virtual machine came be deleted.

Comment: I should also point out that the drivers provided by Apple for your 64 bit Windows 7 are probably of the type where some drivers may need to be loaded by Windows 7 before the installation is completed. For example, there may be a video driver that needs to be loaded when Windows 7 first boots, but has not completed the installation process. Have you made the drivers available to Windows 7 while installing?

Comment: Yes i have, and i have integrated into the installer to ensure that, the method i used to install windows 7 includes a windows 10 installer i have not yet tried the virtual machine method but i doubt it works due to the fact that i also usually get a no bootable disks found error and disk utility reads my USBs as not bootable. (this is from the windows installer without 10 integrated) the 1st half of the installation process works (with windows 10 installer) but the second half is where i encounter this loading 4 green dots error.

Comment: i even tried the DISM command to apply the image itself to be met with the same problem

Comment: BIOS or UEFI and i still face this issue, bootcamp leads to a no bootable devices found error. I will still try the virtualbox method and get back to you.

Comment: Is there a website which documents the steps you took when using the method which *"includes a windows 10 installer"*. I ask because I would like to know what you did and comment, if I see any mistakes.

Comment: As for the virtual machine method, I can say it works for me as I am currently using this method to install Windows 7 and Windows 11 on a 2007 iMac. Back in December 2023, [TAbdiukov](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/369389/tabdiukov) successfully used this method to install Windows 7 on a 2010 Mac mini. (We both followed different steps.) So, you are not the only user who recently has been working on installing Windows 7 on an older Mac with an optical drive.

Comment: Im finally back after trying said method. i can safely say that trying to get windows 7 on it is probably impossible. I had discovered that the efi boot doesn't work at all because MacBooks in the period of 2012 had little to no efi capabilities and using macOS high sierra or older still won't let me boot into an efi flash drive. This is probably due to eeprom bootloader or somekind of bios issue, it doesn't really matter anyway, since I haven't seen anybody else come across my issue. and someone is going to give me their old laptop anyway so ill still be able to use windows 7.

Comment: if someone has faced a similar issue can anyone send a link so I can get this solved?

Comment: You say impossible because of Open Core?

Comment: I mean impossible with or without opencore